# How to check if a build argument starts with certain characters in a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, shell, dockerfile

I am attempting to write some configuration based on the version I am installing in a image. I am fetching the version as a build argument.

```
...
ARG XDEBUG_VERSION=3.1.2
RUN if [ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" = "3.1.2" ]; then echo "yes, it is 3.1.2"; fi
RUN if [ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" = "3*" ]; then echo "yes, starts with 3"; fi
...
```

Checking if the value is `3.1.2` works, but checking if it starts with `3` is not working. Below is the run outupt.

```
Step 20/22 : RUN if [ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" = "3.1.2" ]; then echo "yes, it is 3.1.2"; fi
 ---> Running in e1499d0ec491
yes, it is 3.1.2
Removing intermediate container e1499d0ec491
 ---> ad2439fcec2e
Step 21/22 : RUN if [ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" = "3*" ]; then echo "yes, starts with 3"; fi
 ---> Running in b8da583b4522
Removing intermediate container b8da583b4522
 ---> a9dbc5535002
```

So, How can I check if the build argument starts with certain characters?

Comment: A Dockerfile `RUN` instruction (normally) runs a Bourne shell command; the linked question describes both a short way to do it if you're using GNU Bash, and a longer syntax that works with POSIX shells (including Alpine-based images).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks but I seem to be struggling to find one that works. Also, are you saying that the behaviour of the Docker's `RUN` changes based on the system or shell it is being executed from?

Comment: You can change the `SHELL` that gets used, and on some base images `/bin/sh` is actually GNU bash.  I'd stick to POSIX shell syntax if it's at all an option (and if you ever might want to use an Alpine-based image that doesn't normally have bash).

Comment: @DavidMaze I am on Ubuntu Desktop, How can I change the shell to use `bash` because bash should have no problem interpreting what I am trying above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it e.g. with the help of regex as follows:

```bash
FROM alpine:latest
...
ARG XDEBUG_VERSION=3.1.2
RUN if [ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" = "3.1.2" ]; then echo "yes, it is 3.1.2"; fi
RUN if [[ "$XDEBUG_VERSION" =~ "^3" ]]; then echo "yes, starts with 3"; fi
...
```

Test output with `alpine:latest`:

```bash
docker build --build-arg XDEBUG_VERSION=3.1.2 --progress=plain --no-cache -t string-starts .

#6 [3/3] RUN if [[ "3.1.2" =~ "^3" ]]; then echo "yes, starts with 3"; fi
#6 sha256:7921d7ff89a349bcdb49a0c023101acc5661f87e827cd53a9c7fdb645e0c50f5
#6 0.480 yes, starts with 3
#6 DONE 0.5s

#...

docker build --build-arg XDEBUG_VERSION=4.3.2 --progress=plain --no-cache -t string-starts .

#6 [3/3] RUN if [[ "4.3.2" =~ "^3" ]]; then echo "yes, starts with 3"; fi
#6 sha256:42a1802ce3edbd3f2aa31aa4254cb5216c06f0bb7de75f65b6d0ebba01923e3c
#6 DONE 0.5s
```

Comment: `string =~ regex` doesn't seem to be a valid option for [POSIX test(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128), and this answer might not work on Alpine-based images that don't have the extended GNU tool set.

Comment: The result of test comes from a test with ```alpine:latest```, i.e. it works at least with alpine docker image. I have adjusted my answer by adding alpine as base image used in test.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you please explain me what do you mean by "does not seem to be a valid option for Posix"? [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) one can read that it can be used for matching patterns for Posix as well etc. E.g. a statement from link:  " When you use ‘=~’, the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression pattern and matched accordingly (using the POSIX regcomp and regexec interfaces usually described in regex(3))."

Comment: You're quoting the GNU Bash manual.  "POSIX regular expressions" are a specific thing (the syntax used by classic grep(1)); even if the pattern match uses POSIX REs it doesn't mean POSIX shells accept the `=~` syntax.  `[[ ... ]]` is also explicitly undefined in the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04).

Comment: +1 Thanks, your solution works fine for alpine images. When I asked this question I was trying to get the matching work in the default php image and it hadn't worked. But I faced the same problem again, so revisting. Anyways TA